# AUS/UK dual citizen entering the UK on AUS passport with student visa and taking partner as dependant

Tags: working-visas, student-visa, uk-citizens, australian-citizens

I've been accepted on a full scholarship to do my Doctorate in the UK in Oxbridge. I am a UK/AUS citizen but my partner is only an AUS citizen.

Can I apply to enter the UK under my AUS passport with a student visa and have my partner as a dependent or will I not be allowed because of my UK citizenship?

Comment: For sure you'd need to check if your institution would sponsor it, even if it's possible (which I would assume it isn't).  They might see it as eating into a quota / paying a fee for no reason.

Comment: The institution is willing to sponsor as a student - this is included in the full sponsorship. The dependant visa that’s we want to attach for my partner is something we’ll pay for and is something that they’re happy to do & encourage. But, we need to know if we can do it this way - from our knowledge unlike US and AUS, UK citizens don’t have to legally enter the UK with their UK passport. However, most cases we know are based on people visiting vs. people temporarily moving. We’re also going this way because we definitely want to go back to AUS and the partner visa is excessively expensive!

Comment: Also, if it helps, it is a Clarendon Scholarship and it’s for Oxford University.